# Refrigerator freezes contents, even when set to warmest setting

Tags: repair, appliances, refrigerator, troubleshooting

Our refrigerator, an Amana/Whirlpool ABB1921DEW5, works very well -- rather *too* well, even, as the contents of the refrigerator are freezing, even with the refrigerator thermostat on its warmest setting (1), and irrespective of their location in the fridge (putting it in the door doesn't stop it from freezing).  Other than a stuck thermostat, what could cause this misbehavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *freezer* provides the cooling for the refrigerator. The refrigerator settings usually just adjust vent ports from the freezer. Some units use just vent ports, other units utilize ports along with a fan. Set the fridge at midpoint setting then adjust the *freezer* setting until your stuff in the fridge no longer ices up.